# mysql left join only first row from base table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am hard thinking about how to LEFT JOIN data from one table to the BASE table .. but only for the FIRST row from base table ... is that even possible?

For example:

**TABLE1**

```
item_id  |  insert_datetime  |  value  
---------------------------------------
   2     | 1/1/2014 12:54:05 |   65
   2     | 1/1/2014 12:57:05 |   65
   3     | 8/7/2014 10:01:47 |   87
   3     | 9/8/2014 09:37:21 |   33
   3     | 9/8/2014 09:42:21 |   33
   4     | 2/9/2014 15:22:01 |   58
```

**TABLE2** (left-joined by ID, date [not datetime], value)

```
item_id  |   drop_datetime   |  value  
---------------------------------------
   2     | 1/1/2014 00:00:00 |   65
   3     | 9/8/2014 00:00:00 |   33
```

I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.item_id
, t1.insert_datetime as inserted
, t1.value as ins_value
##
, t2.drop_datetime as cancelled
, t2.value as cld_value
##
FROM table1 t1
##
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.item_id = t1.item_id
AND date(t2.drop_datetime) = date(t1.insert_datetime)
AND t1.value = t2.value
##
WHERE 1=1
```

So it means I need to get which values were cancelled  ... but in case of *item_id* = 2 there was following situation:

Item was shipped on 1/1/2014 12:54:05 (with value 65) ... it was cancelled (1st row in T2), because of wrong parameters and was reshipped 1/1/2014 12:57:05 with the same value

What I get for *item_id* = 2 is:

```
item_id  |     inserted      |  ins_value |  cancelled        |   cld_value
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     | 1/1/2014 12:54:05 |     65     | 1/1/2014 00:00:00 |      65
   2     | 1/1/2014 12:57:05 |     65     | 1/1/2014 00:00:00 |      65
```

But I **NEED** to get this:

```
item_id  |     inserted      |  ins_value |  cancelled        |   cld_value
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     | 1/1/2014 12:54:05 |     65     | 1/1/2014 00:00:00 |      65
   2     | 1/1/2014 12:57:05 |     65     |                   |
```

Because in reality, was only the first cancelled.. is is possible to get this result in MySQL?

***NOTE:*** And an item also could be, unfortunatelly, cancelled for two or threetime in an hour

```
                                   **EDIT 1**
```

If it helps ... all data are in one table with symptom of SHIP(1) or CANCLED(2)

**SOURCE TABLE**

```
id  |  item_id  |  insert_datetime  |  value  |  symptom  
-----------------------------------------------------------
1   |     2     | 1/1/2014 12:54:05 |   65    |     1
2   |     2     | 1/1/2014 00:00:00 |   65    |     2
3   |     2     | 1/1/2014 12:57:05 |   65    |     1
4   |     3     | 8/7/2014 10:01:47 |   87    |     1
5   |     3     | 9/8/2014 09:37:21 |   33    |     1
6   |     3     | 9/8/2014 00:00:00 |   33    |     2
7   |     3     | 9/8/2014 09:42:21 |   33    |     1
8   |     4     | 2/9/2014 15:22:01 |   58    |     1
```

will this help?

```
                                   **POSSIBLE SOLUTION**
```

Ít seems that this works ok:

```
SELECT t1.item_id
, t1.insert_datetime as inserted
, t1.value as ins_value
##
, t2.drop_datetime as cancelled
, t2.value as cld_value
##
FROM table1 t1
##
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.item_id = t1.item_id
AND date(t2.drop_datetime) = date(t1.insert_datetime)
AND t1.value = t2.value
AND t1.id < t2.id   ## <- this should do the trick
##
WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: How do you know only the first was cancelled? I think the data model is wrong. The itemid in table2 should point to a unique id, so you know which one was cancelled. Currently, there is no good way to determine that, and you need to guess a business rule and write a needlessly complex query to work around that problem.

Comment: I do not know this ... i suppose ... but it should be the second one ... actually, it doesn't matter.. i need to see how many items was cancelled and how many of them not ... BUT - in detail :( I agree that the data model is wrong, but I have no chances to change it :(

Comment: I've added more information about original structure .. maybe it will help

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edb97/7)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `item_id` int, `insert_datetime` datetime, `value` int, `symptom` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `item_id`, `insert_datetime`, `value`, `symptom`)
VALUES
    (1, 2, '2014-01-01 12:54:05', 65, 1),
    (2, 2, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 65, 2),
    (3, 2, '2014-01-01 12:57:05', 65, 1),
    (4, 3, '2014-07-08 10:01:47', 87, 1),
    (5, 3, '2014-08-09 09:37:21', 33, 1),
    (6, 3, '2014-08-09 00:00:00', 33, 2),
    (7, 3, '2014-08-09 09:42:21', 33, 1),
    (8, 3, '2014-08-09 00:00:00', 33, 2),
    (9, 3, '2014-08-09 09:48:29', 33, 1),
    (10, 3, '2014-09-02 15:22:01', 58, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.item_id
, t1.insert_datetime as inserted
, t1.value as ins_value
, ifnull(t2.insert_datetime,'') as cancelled
, ifnull(t2.value,'') as cld_value
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
ON t2.item_id = t1.item_id
AND date(t2.insert_datetime) = date(t1.insert_datetime)
AND t1.value = t2.value
AND t1.id < t2.id 
AND t2.symptom = 2
WHERE t1.symptom = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edb97/7/0)**:

```
| ITEM_ID |            INSERTED | INS_VALUE |           CANCELLED | CLD_VALUE |
|---------|---------------------|-----------|---------------------|-----------|
|       2 | 2014-01-01 12:54:05 |        65 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 |        65 |
|       2 | 2014-01-01 12:57:05 |        65 |                     |           |
|       3 | 2014-07-08 10:01:47 |        87 |                     |           |
|       3 | 2014-08-09 09:37:21 |        33 | 2014-08-09 00:00:00 |        33 |
|       3 | 2014-08-09 09:42:21 |        33 | 2014-08-09 00:00:00 |        33 |
|       3 | 2014-08-09 09:48:29 |        33 |                     |           |
|       3 | 2014-09-02 15:22:01 |        58 |                     |           |
```

Comment: same as my solution :) very nice

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SET @rowNoIn:=0;
SET @RowNoCn:=0;
SET @itemIn='';
SET @itemCn='';

select i.*,c.*
from(
  SELECT 
    @rowNoIn:=CASE WHEN @itemIn=item_id THEN @rowNoIn+1 ELSE 1 END AS rowNo
    ,@itemIn:=item_id AS item_id
    ,insert_datetime
    ,value
  FROM table1
  ORDER BY item_id, insert_datetime
)i
left join (
  SELECT 
    @rowNoCn:=CASE WHEN @itemCn=item_id THEN @rowNoCn+1 ELSE 1 END AS rowNo
    ,@itemCn:=item_id AS item_id
    ,drop_datetime
    ,value
  FROM table2
  ORDER BY item_id, drop_datetime)c
on 
  i.item_id = c.item_id
  and i.rowNo = c.rowNo
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8516b/11/4)

**Note** if there is an item cancellation it assumes the first item form table1 is to be cancelled (no matter what date) you can update the code to better suit your need, but hopefully it will lead you into a right direction. You should really consider adding ID to your table1 so you could reference the cancelled records explicitly.